# The ion range slider pointer should not be set at one point

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-range-slider

I'm using ion range slider for date and time. I don't want the two slider to meet at the same point.
[as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUdiR.png)
 Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far to achieve this, as well as where you're getting stuck?

Comment: You can have a look at this link.  http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/09u17wg7/9/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=09u17wg7

Answer (score 1):

I tried **min_interval** and it worked for me :)